# Visual representation of java/maven references

Tags: java, maven

I have a java (maven) project that is quite large. Because of lack of documentation, I'm searching for a visual representation of the various dependencies within the large code base. Is there something that can generate this?

Regards,
Bas Hendriks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/) has a built-in grapher for dependencies in maven projects. [Here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/cxf-dependency-graphs.data/netbeans_dependency_graph.png) is an example of an old NetBeans version.

[image: Source: cxf.apache.org/docs/cxf-dependency-graphs.data/netbeans_dependency_graph.png]

Answer (score 2):

The maven dependency plugin does this

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

The m2e plugin for eclipse can list you the dependencies via a "dependency hirachy" tab in the pom, it can also search and highlight, and lists wether a version is managed, updated or conflicted.

The plugin used to have a graphical representation ala netbeans, but it was apparently dropped. Never used it anyway, since the hirachy table is much more helpful.